# How can I use regexes in Javascript to chop part of a url without specifying fixed length?

Tags: javascript, regex, glob

I'm writing a program to match paths from my filesystem with urls pulled from an SQL database, using Javascript. The URLs pulled are structured like this:

```
http://examplesite.com/wp-content/uploads/YYYY/MM/17818380_1556368674373219_6750790004844265472_n-1.jpg
http://examplesite.com/wp-content/uploads/YYYY/MM/17818380_1556368674373219_6750790004844265472_n.jpg
https://examplesite.com/wp-content/uploads/YYYY/MM/10643960_909727132375975_2074842458_n-44x55.jpg
http://examplesite.com/wp-content/uploads/YYYY/MM/10643960_909727132375975_2078842458_n-320x150.jpg
```

etc. Some have http, some https.

I tried to match the files with the urls with

```
if(files[i] === urlsfromdb[j].substring(50,urlsfromdb[j].length-4))...
```

I want to get everything after the `/` after ...MM, but above sometimes includes the leading slash, which in turns ruins the program. How can I accomplish this with regexes? I wanna get all the jpgs, and I'm using NPM glob to do so.

Additionally, with the files that have -WWWxHHH.jpg, which could be 2 or 3 Ws or Hs, I want to delete those files as well; the URLS from the DB will never actually have them but the files will.

Comment: what is `files` array, what is `urlsfromdb` array, what is `i`, what is `j` ... your "code" is lacking in any detail

Comment: I wanted to compare files in the file system with that data in the DB. The file system has both the original pictures and the ones with the n-1.jpg, n-232x334.jpg etc. in them.

Comment: which still doesn't explain what those variables in your code even are

Answer (score 3):

use a regular expression to remove everything up to the last slash.

```
urlsfromdb[j].replace(/^.*\//, '')
```

Comment: how can I do both that, and remove everything after the `n` in 10643960_909727132375975_2078842458_n-320x150.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the JPEG files you can use a capture group given that all the URLs have MM/ before the image name. Something like this should work:

```
let regex = /.*MM\/([A-Za-z_0-9-]+.jpg)/g;
let match = urlsfromdb[j].match(regex)
let image = match[1]
```